# Laravel: Query with where clause gone wrong

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What I am trying to achieve is to allow teachers to import a student into different classes.

Note: A student can be multiple classes.

The problem is that when I show the list of students in a select dropdown it should return all students except for students that are not in this class (the class being the page that I am on, app.com/classes/5 for example).

```php
$students = User::join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
                ->role('student')
                ->where('group_user.group_id', '!=', $id)
                ->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

This works and shows all students that are not in this specific class **BUT** if a student that's in this class and another class their name appears in the list and as duplicate names.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When MySQL's only_full_group_by mode is turned on, it means that strict ANSI SQL rules will apply when using GROUP BY

You should try to select fields from schema on which you can apply group by instead of select *.

```
$students = User::join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
            ->role('student')
            ->where('group_user.group_id', '!=', $id)
            ->select('users.id', 'other fields you used')
            ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->get();
```

**Not IN** is also useful in your case

```
User::select('fields you used')
    ->role('student')
    ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('group_user')->where('group_id', $id)->pluck('user_id')) // $id = 5
    ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi Ravi. This eliminates showing multiple records of the same student name however it still shows one record of the student which shouldn't be showing as they're already in the specific class.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query to use `distinct()` like so;

```
    $students = User::join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
                ->role('student')
                ->where('group_user.group_id', '!=', $id)
                ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
                ->distinct()
                ->get();
```

You could also `groupBy('users.id')`

```
    $students = User::join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
                ->role('student')
                ->where('group_user.group_id', '!=', $id)
                ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
                ->groupBy('users.id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Hi hazel. Unfortunately neither of these work. I had tried 'distinct' however it still shows duplicate names. As for 'groupBy' this showed an error: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #9 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'app.group_user.group_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @tebrown the group by throws an error b mysql because strict mode is enabled. You can disable it by adding this to mysql connection in config/database.php `'strict' => false`